# Why do floating objects attract?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, surface-tension

Objects floating on the surface of calm water seem to be attracted to one another and tend to come together in a drift. Is this attraction like gravity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a cork float to the side of a glass?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71292/)

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheerios_effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheerios_effect)

Comment: As John Rennie mentioned, it's a side effect of capillary action, which results from surface tension effects, although apparently it's not the surface tension itself which directly causes the attraction, but rather a pressure effect.