# What would the nucleus of a water planet be like?

Tags: nuclear-physics, water, planets, stars, fusion

If we have a planet made out of water, would it be all solid? What about the nucleus? Would it depend on the size of the planet?

Comment: This is very dependent on the details, like how much mass, temperature (not just dependent on distance from a star, internal heating).  A rocky core is more likely as a purely water planet seems unlikely to form.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/527058/44126): a density versus pressure inversion in the "hot ice" phases would probably drive solid- phase convection and transport any high- density metals into the core.

Comment: Also related: the [blueberry Earth paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.10553) by [our own Anders Sandberg](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/165299/anders-sandberg), who wrote a serious answer to [a silly question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/418591/44126), and posted his analysis to arXiv because the question was closed. I learned about this paper driving down the road listening to "RadioLab" on NPR, who interviewed Sandberg and thought we were party poopers for closing the question.

Comment: We should have migrated the question to XKCD.

Comment: [Uranus](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/uranus/overview/) and [Neptune](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/neptune/overview/) are examples of this kind of planet.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a planetary geologist on the flight? Maybe one would know better. Here's the thought process: Lots of pressure, maybe some form of ice (like ice-VII), oh wait...it's going to be hot, way past the triple point. I'm going super critical fluid.

Then I google the image: you decide. If it's Earth sized, go with 5000K, if it's Jupiter size, maybe 30000K - 50000K?...just because that's what I remember about aforementioned planets. The pressure sounds like a basic integral.

[image]