# Why does changing the depth of water affect the position of the cap?

Tags: fluid-statics, home-experiment, surface-tension

[image: Water filled till the brim]
When the water is filled up-to the brim the plastic cap can easily stay in the middle (roughly  ) of the glass.

[image]

When the water is filled till the middle the cap will always come at rest at the corner.

It will be great if somebody can explain why does this happen and also provide me with mathematical proof behind his reasoning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a cork float to the side of a glass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71292/)

Comment: @user7777777 that is half the answer. It doesn't explain why the cap remains in the middle when the glass is full.

Comment: @JohnRennie actually it does: [the top-voted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/71305/21441) (not the accepted one) touches this case too.

Comment: @Bhavay What kind of mathematical proof could be done?

Comment: @AlexTrounev This in regard to the first pic .What am i asking is to prove that at centre sum of net forces = 0 , Also why won't it oscillate(damped oscillations due to viscous force) if the net force is always directed towards centre and rather just stay in centre when displace from the edge.

Comment: @Bhavay It is interesting and not trivial mathematical problem.

Comment: @Bhavay shouldn't a simple free body diagram of the cork explain what you want to know? There is no component of force on the cork except on the horizontal direction which is why there are no oscillations. You would see damped oscillations if you disturbed the water. Also viscous force is redundant if the object is not moving through a fluid.

Comment: @RichardKiddman what do u mean by  -" There is no component of force on the cork except on the horizontal direction " ?

Comment: I apologise for the mistake I made without noticing it. I meant no component except in the vertical direction. Also if you mean why it is not bobbing up and down it's because there is no restoring/reaction force in the vertically down direction. If you tap it on the top, it will oscillate as a matter of fact.

Comment: @RichardKiddman I don't get you. Obviously the net force is in horizontal direction and not in vertical direction.This can be easily proven (again this in reference with the pic 1) if we place the cap at the edge , it will automatically moves towards the centre.If there is a net component of force in the vertical direction then why isn't is moving down and reach the bottom of the glass?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand me. As I have mentioned in my answer below, the constant $vertical$ upward force pushes the bottle cap to occupy the highest position available on the surface of the liquid. In the first picture the highest position is obviously in the centre because the glass pulls back water at the edges at a lower level than the centre while in the second picture the edges have the higher position (see below). If you want to test my answer, put another cork in the water and you'll see they may stick to each other as well.

Comment: And by vertical force I mean upward vertical force because obviously for such a body buoyant force is greater than downward gravitational force.

Comment: @RichardKiddman I have 2 questions for u : 1. Which force(horizontal) drives the cap from edge to centre when cap is released from rest from the edge . (as acc. to u net force in horizontal direction is 0) , 2. Why does it occupy highest position possible. (If we see from energy point of view , totally opposite should happen )?

Comment: Did you read the answer below? Suppose you are at the base of the hill and your feet are stuck to the ground in such a way that you can move on it but you can not float in the air(like a train) Now if I apply a force from below would you not slide to the highest possible point until you can go no more higher? That should explain your query.

Answer (score 2):

This is something known as the Cheerios Effect. Because of the buoyancy of the water, a light object, for example a cork or bottle cap is forced to occupy the highest position on the surface of the water. Now as shown in the image:

[image]
The highest point of the water is at it's edges because of the strong force of adhesion between the glass and the water. So naturally the bottle cap moves to the edge to occupy the highest position available.
Interestingly when filled upto the brim, the same force of adhesion pulls the water at the edges down but the water at the centre has no pull on it (due to force of adhesion, cohesive force is omnipresent) and now the highest point is at the centre so that's where the cap resides.
This also means that in theory (never tried it) if you filled half the cup with mercury the bottle cap should stay at the centre because of its convex meniscus.

Comment: For all those who downvoted this, what is the correct answer then?

Comment: I would guess people are downvoting because your answer is wrong. The correct answer can be read [in the question I linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71292/why-does-a-cork-float-to-the-side-of-a-glass).

Comment: I didn't downvote. But this is what being explained in the [top voted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/71305/238167) (not the accepted one) to the linked question. It also relates to the Cheerios effect. I guess there are two possible explanations to this observation. The other reason is explained by John Rennie in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/71304/238167).

Comment: @John Rennie the accepted answer did not have any given reason. It was a guess as the author clearly mentioned and it's ambiguity is apparent because it just says the sides are just lowest energy configurations. If you look deeply the Cheerios effect and what I have written IS the lowest energy configuration possible because of buoyancy (which in a way is related to gravity) and surface tension. It isn't wrong, I know what I'm saying.